# how to send multiple of html email to list or array of users(with emails) in Grails?

Tags: grails, html-email, gsp

I have a user domain and I want to send an email to all the users in one go.
However i can send email individually but not sure how to deal with multiple emails send.
My emailService looks like this:

```
def mailSender
    def mailMessage // a "prototype" email instance
    ApplicationContext applicationContext

    /**
     * Send a list of emails.
     *
     * @param mails a list of maps
     */
    boolean sendEmails(mails) {
        def retval = true
        // Build the mail messages
        def messages = []
        for (mail in mails) {
            // create a copy of the default message
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage()

            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "ISO-8859-1");
            helper.setFrom(mail.from);
            helper.setTo(getInternetAddresses(mail.to));
            helper.setSubject(mail.subject);
            helper.setText(mail.text, true);
            if(mail.bcc)
            helper.setBcc(getInternetAddresses(mail.bcc));
            if(mail.cc)
            helper.setCc(getInternetAddresses(mail.cc));
            messages << mimeMessage
        }

        // Send them all together
        try {
            log.debug("mailsender")
            mailSender.send(messages as MimeMessage[])
        }
        catch (MailException e) {
            log.error "Failed to send emails: $e.message", e
            retval = false
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            log.error "Failed to send emails: $e.message", e
            retval = false
        }
        return retval
    }
```

I dont know how to use it on gsp to make it work.
I need to know what variables or array i need to pass to emailer service and how.

Answer (score 1):

wow, that looks like a lot of extra work.  Use the [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail).  [Docs](http://gpc.github.io/grails-mail/docs/guide/3.%20Sending%20Email.html#3.1%20Sender%20And%20Recipient) show you how to sent to multiple recipients.

```
sendMail {
    to "someoneorg.com", "someone.elseorg.com"
    …
}
```

Comment: We need some mechanism like, when you do `run-app` framework should detect and prompt `"Save some energy, use ${thisPlugin} instead. Stay Groovy!!"` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Gregg is absolutely right you are doing lots of extra work. Best is to use [mail](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setTo%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) plugin.

But if you still wants to use your approach then

`setTo()` method of `MimeMessageHelper` class can receive multiple email address, like

```
helper.setTo("mkb@test.com", "mb@test.com");
```

Read the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setTo%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array of String to helper.setTo method
e.g.

```
String[] address = {"test0@gmail.com", "test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com"};
        helper.setTo(address);
```